# Is there a smart way of checking whether a custom object is within an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

Given I've got an [array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) `arr` of instances of a custom class `My_class`. This class has got a couple of different instance variables. Let's call them `:name` (a String), `:is_processed` (a Boolean) and `:date` (a [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html)). All of them are readable.

What is the best way of checking, whether another given instance of `My_class` (call it `newbe`) is already in the array based on the content of the aforementioned instance variables?

Using `arr.include?(newbe)` will not work as this compares the object IDs, doesn't it?
Can I override the way `Array#include?` compares two objects?

---

**Speaking in code**

```
class My_class
  attr_reader :name, :is_processed, :date

  def initialize(_name, _proc, _d)
    @name = _name
    @is_processed = _proc
    @date = _d
  end
end
```

somewhere else

```
first = My_class.new("First", false, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6))
second = My_class.new("Second", true, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6))
third = My_class.new("Third", false, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,3,2,1))
newbe = My_class.new("Second", true, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6))

arr = [first, second, third]
arr.include?(newbe)  # => false but should be true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compare instances of you class, so include `comparable`, define a `<=>` method and you have added these methods to your class instances:

<,  <=,  ==,  >,  >=,  between? (#include? uses #== ).

```
require 'date'
class My_class
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :name, :is_processed, :date

  def initialize(_name, _proc, _d)
    @name = _name
    @is_processed = _proc
    @date = _d
  end

  def <=>(other)
    [self.name, self.is_processed, self.date]<=>[other.name, other.is_processed, other.date]
  end
end
first = My_class.new("First", false, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6))
second = My_class.new("Second", true, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6))
third = My_class.new("Third", false, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,3,2,1))
newbe = My_class.new("Second", true, DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6))

arr = [first, second, third]
p arr.include?(newbe)  # => true
#you could do arr.sort, but they are sorted allready by accident...
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm going to implement this approach as I think it's the most generic one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `any?` with a block.

```
my_arr.any? { |o| o.kind_of?(MyClass) }
```

You can also use `detect` or `find` if you want the matched object back.  These are all standard methods on `Enumerable`, which most collection-ish classes mix in.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. As far as I don't want to know the index of the matching item (or a count of how many items matches) this is probably the nicest way. However, I should substitute `o.kind_of(MyClass)` with `(o.name == newbe.name && o.is_processed == newbe.is_processed && o.date == newbe.date)`. PS: I'll wait for some more answers before accepting one.

Comment: `! my_arr.grep(MyClass).empty?` should also work, based on classes implementing `===`. might be a slight headscratcher for the maintainer though.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider whether it would make sense to redefine == for your custom class, like this:

```
class My_class
  def ==(other)
    (other.is_a? My_class) && 
    (other.name == @name)  &&
    (other.is_processed == @is_processed) &&
    (other.date == @date)
  end
end
```

If you do this, Array#include? will work the way you want.